# how come an undeclared variable is outputting a value

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu

In my function `sumofrange` I decided to output an undeclared variable just to learn the different compiler errors in C++. To my surprise, `time` seems to output 1 even though it is not declared anywhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int  sumOfrange( int   lower, int  upper){
   cout<<time<<endl;
   return ((( (pow(upper,2)) + upper) - ((pow(lower,2)) + lower)) / 2);
}

int main(){  
    cout<<sumOfrange(7,100)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is why namespaces are important and `using namespace std;` is sometimes dangerous.

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: btw there is no such thing as an "undeclared variable". If it was undeclared you could not use it

Comment: @ForceBru Remove `using namespace std;`, and you'll get the same output for `std::cout << time << '\n';` on a lot of implementation.

Comment: Even if `using namespace std;` should probably be removed here, the real solution would be to enable your compiler warning (`-W -Wall` with clang / gcc) to obtain a warning for such code.

Comment: I disagree with the dupe target. [Removing `using namespace std;`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd9c9486c617ce8d) has no effect on the issue.

Comment: BTW, the [`std::pow` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is for floating point.  To square numbers, use multiplication, e.g. `upper * upper` and `lower * lower`.  The multiplication is more efficient since it doesn't require a function call.

Answer (score 4):

You are outputting the address of a [std::time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function declared in a `<ctime>` header. You are also using a `using namespace std;` statement. Why that should be avoided is explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Depending on the compiler and the platform you might get the hexadecimal output similar to (0x)`00DC52E0` if using a VC++ compiler on Windows or a number `1` if using a g++ compiler on Linux.

Comment: Yet another example of the subtle pitfalls of using `using namespace std;`.

Comment: not sure if a function has a value. Anyhow its the adress of the function

Comment: I believe it is being cast to a `bool` and returned as 1. `cout<<(void*)time<<endl;` outputs an address.

Comment: @Persixty You should not mix function pointers and `void *`. Use `&time` instead.

Comment: @nwp I agree. But `&time` just outputs 1 as well. Forcing a cast makes it output some kind of address...

Comment: @Persixty Interesting. Apparently there is no overload for function pointers on `std::cout` which only leaves the implicit conversion to `bool`. Someone should fix that in a standards proposal.

Comment: @nwp Crazy, huh?